# capybara and reloading iframe with javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, rspec, capybara

so I have a rails app with an IFrame, and at some point I reload that IFrame via javascript and it's content changes.

So I'm trying to test that behavior with following code

```
sleep 3
within_frame('email-content') do
    page.should have_content "<h1>Email content</h1>"
end
```

When I run it with selenium I can see that IFrame's content has updated, however capybara still sees old content. Making it wait longer before checking it's content does not work either. Any help is appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Can you add reproduction case (relevant HTML/JS) so that we will be able to reproduce it?

Comment: I am having a similar issue, were you able to find any clues?